# Can't get sublimelineter-json to work on mac for indentation

Tags: json, sublimelinter

I installed the sublimelinter plugin along with the sublimelinter-json plugin however - I'm not getting any errors for incorrect indentation.  I'd like to enforce 2 spaces indentation. This is what is defined:

```
"linters" : {
    "json": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [
                ],
                "excludes": [],
                "strict": true
            },
}
```